# Sort list based on calculated index of properties

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, indexing

I have following class.

```
 public class Header
    {
        public long CombinedIndex { get; private set; }
        public int Key { get; set; } //Unique
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }// True or false
        public DateTime? AvailableDate { get; set; } // null or date value
        public int Index { get; set; } // a number and can be same among other Header 

        public void CalculateCombinedIndex()
        {
            CombinedIndex = Key + (IsRequired ? 0 : 1) + Index + (AvailableDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue).Ticks;
        }
    }
```

I am expected around 50,000 instances
of it in an array. I need to sort them in following order:

- First based on IsRequired
- Then Index
- Then Available date (date value near to current date)
- Key (primary key)

Does it make sense to say sum all these property value and
derive a unique number and then only sort that number. 
Later, the list of Header can be converted to dictionary where
Key is CombinedIndex and my already sorted array can lookup that
dictionary in order I iterated the array. How efficient and 
promising this all looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to perform comparison operations based on a projected key from a given type, I find it helps to have a `KeyComparer` class that can create an `IComparer<TSource>` instance from a `Func<TSource, TKey>` delegate. This works especially well with the new tuple syntax introduced in C# 7. Here's an example of the resulting syntax:

```
// Create an IComparer<Header> instance based on your combined key.
var comparer = KeyComparer.Create((Header h) => (h.IsRequired, h.Index, h.AvailableDate, h.Key));

List<Header> headers = ...

// Sort the list using the combined key.
headers.Sort(comparer);

// Convert to a dictionary keyed by the combined key.
var dict = headers.ToDictionary(comparer.KeySelector);
```

And here's a sample implementation of the class. (For a more detailed explanation, see [my blog post](https://dogmamix.com/cms/blog/KeyComparer).)

```
public static class KeyComparer
{
    public static KeyComparer<TSource, TKey> Create<TSource, TKey>(
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IComparer<TKey> innerComparer = null)
    {
        return new KeyComparer<TSource, TKey>(keySelector, innerComparer);
    }
}

public class KeyComparer<TSource, TKey> : Comparer<TSource>
{
    protected internal KeyComparer(
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        IComparer<TKey> innerComparer = null)
    {
        KeySelector = keySelector ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
        InnerComparer = innerComparer ?? Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    }

    public Func<TSource, TKey> KeySelector { get; }
    public IComparer<TKey> InnerComparer { get; }

    public override int Compare(TSource x, TSource y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;
        if (x == null)
            return -1;
        if (y == null)
            return 1;

        TKey xKey = KeySelector(x);
        TKey yKey = KeySelector(y);
        return InnerComparer.Compare(xKey, yKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do in .net 4.6.2 for KeyComparer.Create method? I mean to say that without using Tuple syntax.

Comment: I think this is it:             var comparer = KeyComparer.Create((Header h) => Tuple.Create(!h.IsRequired, h.Index, h.AvailableDate, h.Key));

Comment: @JayNanavaty: Exactly. It's slightly less performant than the C# 7 version since `Tuple.Create` instantiates a reference type, but that won't matter for 50,000 records.

Comment: Is there any way to specify sort ascending or descending for h.Index, h.AvailableDate or so?

Comment: @JayNanavaty: I don't think it's possible to make tuples sort other than with the default comparer for their components. If you don't mind adulterating the values of your keys, you could apply negation to achieve that effect: `KeyComparer.Create((Header h) => Tuple.Create(!h.IsRequired, -h.Index, -h.AvailableDate.Ticks, h.Key));` Otherwise, you'll have to create a custom comparer.

Comment: Thanks about negation. I already used it for bool fields and it works all good. By using custom comparer, do you mean to specify one which will handle all the keys? Do you mean the one which is optional parameter in keycomparer?

Comment: I meant a custom `IComparer<T>` implementation, similar to the `BoxComp` example shown on the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx). You can put in your custom logic there; e.g. `if (x.Index.CompareTo(y.Index) != 0) return -x.Index.CompareTo(y.Index);`

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with LINQ:

```
var ordered = list
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.IsRequired)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Index)
    .ThenBy(x=> x.AvailableDate)
    .ThenBy(x=> x.Key);
```

Only in case of ties the next condition will be used. So no need to create a combined index which makes it very difficult to change the order logic and which seems to be broken anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can use List.Sort().

```
public class Header : IComparable
{
    public long CombinedIndex { get; private set; }
    public int Key { get; set; } //Unique
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }// True or false
    public DateTime? AvailableDate { get; set; } // null or date value
    public int Index { get; set; } // a number and can be same among other Header 

    public void CalculateCombinedIndex()
    {
        CombinedIndex = Key + (IsRequired ? 0 : 1) + Index + (AvailableDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue).Ticks;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Header otherHeader = obj as Header;
        if (otherHeader != null)
        {
            if (this.IsRequired && !otherHeader.IsRequired)
                return 1;
            if (!this.IsRequired && otherHeader.IsRequired)
                return -1;
            if (this.Index > otherHeader.Index)
                return 1;
            if (this.Index < otherHeader.Index)
                return -1;
            //// ....
            return 0;
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Temperature");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the [Comparision<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) or [IComparer<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads of `Sort` would be less intrusive on the class.

Comment: @KennethK.  Same basic idea.  In the Class can be convenient.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Yes it accomplishes the goal, but no you've now locked your comparison logic in. What happens when you want to compare the items in a different manner? You can only implement the interface once. Do you now make some giant `case` statement (e.g.)?

Comment: @KennethK. Not going to debate it with you.  OP can decide which route he wants to take.

Comment: This sounds interesting choosing between Icomparable over Comparision and IComparer. However, before I decide upon this, do you see any cons in using CombinedIndex? I thought it would be much faster and lightweight compared to the two approaches mentioned here. Any thoughts?

Comment: As I will iterate anyway this list once when I filter it based on some other criteria and can calculate combinedIndex upfront. Perhaps it might make sorting faster.

Comment: @JayNanavaty Give it a try.  That sum seems problematic to me.  I would not have suggested this if I liked your idea.

Comment: @JayNanavaty Don't guess about performance enhancements. Profile your code and locate the bottlenecks...then optimize.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. I am just going to try all these out and will share DotTrace result of performance to see how it goes. :)